# xml / html dynamically updating email signature?

Tags: email, outlook, signature

Does anyone know a way to put dynamic content in email sinagure ? (outlook) I know a way to use image src, but i'm wondering if there's a way to pull xml/html content from web, so we can dynamically update our signatures?

Thanks in advance for any kind of help

Comment: I have one question: HUH - Seriously?

Comment: Yes, why not? It's 2014.

Comment: Maybe some VBScript could be used ..

Comment: That does not change the fact that the whole idea is fraught with security concerns that have not changed ever. There is no security model that will allow dynamic signatures or other content in an Email

Comment: This might be stupid, but what's the problem getting data from xml? As far as i know, it is not exploitable. Especially if you target xml directly. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @LeosLiterak any live example or something? I'm not familiar with vb at all...

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with Microsoft programming at all. But I know that many MS Office programs like Excel or Project has scripting capabilities and there exists plugins for Outlook. So if linkedin or evernote can update outlook user interface, then it may be possible to update content of created email as well.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this dynamically. Everything other than standard html and css is either blocked or marked as spam in most email clients. Your hosted image technique (where you can update it at any time) is the only way.